# Reduce mousemove events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've this code:

```
$("body").mousemove(function (event) {
    var lowestspanelm = findNearestSpan(gg_phone_spans, event);
});
```

During mouse move this is generating too many events and increasing CPU load which is taking around 1 minute or so to become normal.

To reduce this load what I want is to act only when mouse has stopped for at least 1/2 second.

What is the way to do it?

Comment: you could use a `debounce` function, such as lodash's debounce

Comment: Find a throttle or debounce function that will reduce the number of calls.

Comment: https://programmingwithmosh.com/javascript/javascript-throttle-and-debounce-patterns/

Comment: See https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function for a debounce function without any framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented this is generally called a `debounce` function, and is available in many general purpose libraries. It is also fairly easy to write (a simple version) yourself.

```js
$(document).on("mousemove",debounce(function(event) {
  console.log("This will only happen after you stop moving the mouse for 1/2 second")
},500));

function debounce(fn, time){
    let timer = null;
    return (evt) => {
       clearTimeout(timer);
       timer = setTimeout( () => fn(evt), time);
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 9):

Though your question points in a direction that you need a debounce function, my advise is that you try a throttle function instead.

A debounced function will only fire when there are no more incoming events
A throttled function will fire only at regular intervals

```
$("body").mousemove(throttle(function (event) {                
    var lowestspanelm = findNearestSpan(gg_phone_spans,event);
}, 500));
```

This will fire only every .5 seconds (= 500 ms) as long as there are incoming events

You won't need jQuery for this.

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', throttle(function (event) {
    var lowestspanelm = findNearestSpan(gg_phone_spans,event);
}, 500));
```

Here is a demonstration of the differences.
If you hover over the *NORMAL* element the background color will change with every pixel moved.
If you move inside the *THROTTLE* element, the color will change only every half of a second as long as you are moving.
If you move inside the *DEBOUNCE* element, the color will change only .5 seconds after you stopped moving (or moved out of the element).

Here are debounce and throttle next to each other

```js
function debounce(callback, wait) {
  var timeout;
  return function(e) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);

    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      callback(e);
    }, wait);
  }
}

function throttle(callback, wait) {
  var timeout
  return function(e) {
    if (timeout) return;
    timeout = setTimeout(() => (callback(e), timeout=undefined), wait)
  }
}

function onMove(e) {
  e.target.classList.toggle('gold')
}
document.querySelector('.normal').addEventListener('mousemove', onMove)
document.querySelector('.throttle').addEventListener('mousemove', throttle(onMove, 500))
document.querySelector('.debounce').addEventListener('mousemove', debounce(onMove, 500))
```

```css
.normal,
.throttle,
.debounce {
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;
  margin: 25px;
  background: silver;
  border: 1px solid gold;
}

.normal.gold,
.throttle.gold,
.debounce.gold {
  background: gold;
}

body {
display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="normal">NORMAL</div>

<div class="throttle">THROTTLE</div>

<div class="debounce">DEBOUNCE</div>
```

Comment: Really nice demonstration of the differences.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way is to use timeouts:

```
var mouseTimeout;

$("body").mousemove(function (event) {                
  clearTimeout(mouseTimeout);
  mouseTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    var lowestspanelm = findNearestSpan(gg_phone_spans,event);

  }, 500);
});
```

You can adjust the 500 to have it trigger more or less often.

Comment: <strike>With that solution, `findNearestSpan` isn't called until the mouse stops!</strike> Nevermind, I understood the question wrong.

Comment: @SteeveDroz Isnt that _exactly what was asked_ "To reduce this load what I want is to act only when mouse has stopped for at least 1/2 second"

Comment: The last function call will happen 500ms after the mouse has stopped moving. It is pretty much what you asked.

Comment: Once more: Nevermind, I understood the question wrong.